# How I host asp.net mvc core application to linux server app is developed on window platform

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have to host webapplication which is built on vs 2017 asp.net core window platform.
So do I can host to Linux server?
or its required ubuntu platform for building?

Comment: Check [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1) or [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can host to linux server. no ubuntu platform required for building asp.net mvc core application.

There are steps to host app on linux or ubantu server.

Step-1. Publishing .net core project in window platform. where project is created.

Step-2. Move publishing build of .net core project folder to linux or ubantu platform.

Step-3. Click on published folder and open that folder -> click on open file in terminal.

Step-4. Below is command to run .net core project in linux machine.

Step-5. Command name - Dotnet projectname.dll EXample: dotnet Webapp1.dll  where "webapp1.dll" is the dll of your project.

Step-6. Open browser And Run localhost:5000 in browser. (By default 5000 port is used.)